# Piling up images from the bottom to the top in div

Tags: css, html

Say I have a div container with a fixed width and height. Now, I want to add images to the container, with images piling on top of each other.

If I just fix the width of the container, and add images inside it, they will pile up from top to bottom. How can I make them pile up from bottom to top?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work in modern browsers, you could use `display: table-cell`:

css

```
.container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;    /* act like image */
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

[An example on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroen/yF8Tw/)

By the way, that only aligns them to the bottom, it still shows the first block on top...